# Automatically Copy Paste Cells with Formula then Paste it to Values In Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Good day. I hope you are doing fine. I am just new in Google sheet and I don't know how to do this using Google App script. Please help.

**Cell A1** serves as a reference to which **last row** should it paste the formula/values.

**Cell C2:D2** has a formula.

**Cell C3:D6** does not contain a formula.

I want to automatically do this steps below using Google script.

**1st Step:** Copy Cell C2:D2 and paste it as FORMULA in Cell C3:D6.

**2nd Step:** Copy Cell C3:D6 and paste it as VALUES in Cell C3:D6.

I am using this script below but it does not work.

```
  const sheetName = "Sheet21";
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const row = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  const range = sheet.getRange("C3:D" + row);
  //range.copyTo(range, { contentsOnly: true }); 
  //range.copyTo(range, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false); 
  range.setValues(range.getValues());

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet21";
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const row = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  const range = sheet.getRange("C3:D" + row);
  
  // --- I modified the below script.
  sheet.getRange("C2:D2").copyTo(range, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  range.copyTo(range, { contentsOnly: true });
}
```